# Having trouble posting a photo directly to Instagram with InstagramApiSharp

Tags: c#, .net, api, instagram, sharp

I use the following code to post photos directly to Instagram
But it gives error challenge_required.
Where do you think the problem is?

```
        private async void btn_i_s_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inbox = await ctx.api.MessagingProcessor.GetDirectInboxAsync(PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1));
            var threadId = inbox.Value.Inbox.Threads.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Title == txt_u_p.Text).ThreadId;
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.ShowDialog();
            var imageUp = new InstaImage()
            {
                Uri = op.FileName
            };
            var image = await ctx.api.MessagingProcessor.SendDirectPhotoAsync(imageUp, threadId);
            if (image.Succeeded)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sended ...");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(image.Info.Message);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can this help : [Challenge Require](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/wiki/Challenge-require)?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static async void EditPorfilePhoto(string Picpath)
{
    var PicByte = File.ReadAllBytes(Picpath);
    var picrequest = await       api.AccountProcessor.GetRequestForEditProfileAsync();
    if (picrequest.Succeeded) 
    {
        var editpic = await api.AccountProcessor.ChangeProfilePictureAsync(PicByte);
        if( editpic.Succeeded)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"{User.UserName} ProFilePicture Deleted  !."); 
        }
          
    }           
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).